# How to ask "how is my note calculated"?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I want to ask in German:

> How is the note of the course calculated? Do you consider the obtained points of the homeworks or only the number of the handed over homeworks?

I think it could be:

> Wie wird die Note des Kurs berechnet? Verwenden Sie die kriegte Punkte der Hausaufgaben oder nur die Anzahl der abgegebenen Hausaufgaben?

Is this right? I'm not very sure about the "verwenden". Can anyone help me? Thank you!

Comment: This is a case for ELL, but I’m pretty sure using *note* to mean *(Schul-) Note* is a false friend. To the best of my knowledge, a *note* is either a *Notiz,* a *Banknote* or a musical *Note.*

Comment: @Jan, right, it should be “grade” or “mark”.

Answer (score 4):

> Wie wird die Note des Kurs berechnet? Verwenden Sie die kriegte Punkte der Hausaufgaben oder nur die Anzahl der abgegebenen Hausaufgaben?

The verb **verwenden** is ok in this context.

If you want, you could also use the construct **etwas (zu etwas) heranziehen** (your sentence would then be “Ziehen Sie die erreichten Punkte der Hausaufgaben (zur Berechnung der Note) heran, oder nur die Anzahl der abgegebenen Hausaufgaben?”). Please note that this sounds a bit old and would only be used in formal written German, it’s rather unusual in oral German.

However, there are some other minor (and one major) mistakes:

- You don’t say <del>die **kriegte** Punkte</del>, but “die **erreichten** Punkte” instead!
  Alternatives would be “die **erhaltenen** Punkte” or “die **bekommenen** Punkte”.
- The genitive of *der Kurs* is *des Kurs**es***.
- There should be a **comma (`,`)** before *oder*.
- To let the sentence sound nicer and make clear that it’s not “either *only* the points or *only* the number of homework handed in”, but rather “number *and* points, or *only* number”, you could add the word **auch**:

  > Verwenden Sie **auch** die erreichten Punkte …

Comment: While you do not say this either, the grammatically correct form would be "die gekriegten Punkte".

Comment: Please don’t mention every single mistake the OP made in an answer. Rather, if they are not part of the original question being asked (such as the comma and the question mark; the question was mainly about wordings), edit the question. Maybe leave a note to explain why you edited things. Because the question mark is extremely obvious, I edited it into the question and removed it from your answer.

Comment: @Jan Ok, I agree on the question mark, but the question is "*Is this right? I'm not very sure about the "verwenden".*" - so the OP asks for a full review of his translation, but with special attention on the verb "verwenden". Anyway, I would say that correcting a mistake in the answer and pointing it out to the OP this way is better than ignoring or silently editing it away...

Answer (score 2):

Also possible: "Wie wird meine Note errechnet?"

Answer (score 1):

While *verwenden* is not wrong, a better choice would be *berücksichtigen*.

So your sentence could be

> Wie wird die Note des Kurses berechnet? (Verwenden / )Berücksichtigen Sie die erreichten Punkte der Hausaufgaben, oder nur (die Anzahl der abgegebenen Hausaufgaben / ) deren Anzahl?

*Verwenden* can be translated as *to use* or *to make use of*, while *berücksichtigen* translates to *take into account*.
Since the marks are not used as such, but only respected, or taken into account, *berücksichtigen is the better word choice.